# Own page keeps redirecting to other site. How to solve?

Tags: web, response.redirect, redirect

My website's homepage keeps redirecting to my other website, which is odd because I didn't do anything to make that happen. I already checked index.html and it is clean. What can it be? The site I am redirected to is also my site, but of course I don't want that to happen.

I hope someone can help me out.

PS: I don't believe I am hacked, because I am referred to my site.

I am using `Wordpress` btw.

Comment: Check your `.js` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright. How odd it might be and might sound, it was `Google's Adsense` banners that were causing this redirection. I had set a "**show banners of this site**" via `Adsense` if there were no ads... I removed the ad from my `sidebar` and now it is not redirecting anymore.

Damn it.

Answer (score 0):

I would write a comment but don't have the reputation to do so yet...
Just a thought: did you **copy** one website from the other? Could there be a link in there somewhere that wasn't changed to the location of your new website?

Comment: I did something like that, but on localhost I am not getting an error like that. Anyhow, I am going to check all my files now. It is very very odd.

Comment: Nope, nothing at all. Damn this is frustrating.